# Background service to access websql/sqlite in android?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I'm doing jquery mobile application for android with html5. We use websql for the local data storage. Is it possible to run a service in background which can access this db and upload some data from local DB to the server SQL DB? I really don't have any idea about it. Please suggest.

Heard that in browser we can't do such background services. If I move my data from websql to android supported SQLite, is it possible to run a service to upload this data?

I wants to have,

1. Run the service & upload data even if the application is closed.
2. Send & complete request if I redirect through my application pages

Comment: possible duplicate of [background HTML5 WebApps on Android 2.3+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331245/background-html5-webapps-on-android-2-3)

Comment: Currently I don't think this is possible and I'm not so sure this would be a great idea. When I close the browser I don't want a service to still run, sounds shady to me. I would look into PhoneGap or a Native App for running background services when applications are closed

Comment: @PhillPafford Thanks for the reply. I agree with you. So the first point I'm skipping. But second point is critical. Actually I tried to implement this with ajax asynchronous call, but when I refresh or navigating to other pages it is stopping the process. On going request will stop or will not complete the sending requests.